# How to deserialize an string-serialized Erlang term into a JInterface object in Java?

Tags: erlang

My interface system provides a result from the Erlang world sending a string reppresentation of an erlang term, such as a list of tuples:

```
[ {"key1" , ["AAA", "BBB"] } , {"key2" , ["CCC", "DDD"] } ]
```

Once I receive this string in Java, I want to parse it (deserialize) using the OTP library ( com.ericsson.otp.OtpErlangList, etc).

I do not want to connect directly to Erlang OTP or use Json or Xml in my situation ( trying to handle it as native as possible, if possible ).

When I convert the string to a OtpErlangList, I get a list of integers, so overall I believe it simply converted to the character codes since a string in erlang is a list of codes. It appears there is no de-serializer in JInterface. If this is the case then I am forced to go for JSON.

There must be a way, since the OtpErlangObject ( and all other sub classes) have a toString method. Why would they not give the ability to reverse that ( fromString(String str) ) ?

**Reiterating:** How to convert an erlang term string representation into JInterface objects in Java right from a String ( **without** node connections, interfacing with JSON, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to the collaboration here is final answer:

The final answer is simply that there is no erlang term string representation deserializer for Java (or other language) as far as I know. But...

1) At the moment there is no Java Interface (JInterface included) that supports the deserialization of an erlang term from native **string** term representation

2) Jinterface supports the OtpInputStream, but it expects the **Erlang External Term Format** as described [here](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html)

3) The above external term format is binary data. The transmission of the data to a Java interface must be done as such using the [term_to_binary](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#term_to_binary-1) BIF.

4) Once the data is streamed back to an OtpErlangObject on the java side (using JInterface), it can be expanded towards its inner data, casting the OtpErlangObject to whatever was sent ( OtpErlangList, OtpErlangTuple, etc)

Erlang side:

```
ExternalFormatBinData = term_to_binary(MyTermToBeSent),
%transmit data using messaging or other media
...
```

The Java side of the code

```
OtpInputStream otpInputStream = new OtpInputStream(receivedBinaryDataArrayOfBytes)
OtpErlangObject erlangObject = otpInputStream.read_any();
OtpErlangList erlangList = (OtpErlangList) erlangObject // replace OtpErlangList to whatever is being sent
...
```

Answer (score 2):

JInterface doesn't provide such functionality AFAIK. It is intended for communication with Erlang nodes via Erlang internal network protocol. In your case I would probably write a parser with something like [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/). Basing on a grammar, you can build any object structure you like.

Answer (score 1):

You said as native as possible and no json etc.. but I would use [protocol-buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) or [thrift](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/) if you make calls to erlang from java. There is also [bert](https://github.com/blog/531-introducing-bert-and-bert-rpc) but I haven't experimented with it. I think these would be safer than dealing with string de/serialization and save you feature headaches.

Comment: Check out the [basho protobuf](https://github.com/basho/erlang_protobuffs) repository for using protobuffs with Erlang.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how parsing the Erlang string is any more native than parsing JSON.  However, if you really want to do this, you might be able to use the `OtpInputStream` class, and initialize it with they byte array of the `String` you want to parse.  Then call `read_any` to get an `OtpErlangObject`. The documentation is here: [OtpInputStream](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/jinterface/java/com/ericsson/otp/erlang/OtpInputStream.html).

Comment: thanks. I actually tried that before this posting, OtpInputStream does not work as it expects a specific erlang format used to data transmission, which differs from the string representation. I updated my question showing that example.  About the reason to why I believe this is more native is that it takes a flash of computation to produce the erlang string representation from erlang, and constructing a JInterface erlang object has also a toString() method that is straight forward. It simply appears to me that this would require less computation than bridging this to JSON or XML.

Comment: Just to complete my comment above, I am puzzled that a so-claimed java interface for erlang (JInterface) does not offer a textual driven serialization approach ( which would extend to a wider range of media transmission and storage). I believe that the erlang object format is strong and compact, just like JSON.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/metadave/etp will convert a String into a Java object model (without node connections, interfacing with JSON, etc). Simply build a JInterface model from this in memory representation.

> The final answer is simply that there is no erlang term string representation deserializer 
>   for Java (or other language) as far as I know.

That's what the etp project is (above).